# creating Advanced CEL expression for Context aware access rule

Tags: geofencing

We have had issues with accounts being compromised and "attacked" from other countries. I create the Geofence in context awareness and its great, however I need a bypass for Staff and students that are traveling throughout the year. Moving between OUs not not acceptable and would like to have a group - corotravelersgworkspace@shsd.org to added as a bypass that I can add staff and students to and remove as needed and not have to move them all around. that would cause other issues.